# Java change .jar file display icon

Tags: java, jar

I tried to change the display [**icon**](http://i59.tinypic.com/9sqnhy.png) of my jar file that I exported via Eclipse. After a search on the web I found this code:

```
"frmPos.setIconImage( new imageIcon( getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "PATH/TO/YourImage.png" ) ) );"
```

but it doesn't work and it gives me the this error "Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
imageIcon cannot be resolved to a type  window_layout.java  /PostOffice/src line 150    Java Problem". Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Have I placed in wrong place the code which change the jar icon? Below is a sample of my code. Thanks.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;


public class window_layout {

    private JFrame frmPos;
    private ArrayList<Shipment> shipment_list;
    private Shipment temp;

    private boolean international_destination_bl;
    private boolean priority_bl;
    private int domestic_counter;
    private int international_counter;
    private String shipment_type;
    private float weight;
    private int postal_code;
    private String country;
    private float domestic_total_cost;
    private float international_total_cost;
    private int shipments_counter;

    private String str_weight = "Βάρος:";
    private String text = null;

    private boolean JComboBox_bl;
    private boolean JComboBox_1_bl;
    private boolean JComboBox_2_bl;
    private boolean JComboBox_3_bl;

    private JFrame border;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;

    private JTextPane textPane_3;
    private JTextPane textPane_5;

    private JComboBox comboBox;
    private JComboBox comboBox_1;
    private JComboBox comboBox_2;
    private JComboBox comboBox_3;
    private JTextField textField_3;

    private TextArea messageBox;




    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    window_layout window = new window_layout();
                    window.frmPos.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public window_layout() 
    {
        initialize();

        shipment_list = new ArrayList<Shipment> ( );

        international_destination_bl = false;
        domestic_counter = 0;
        international_counter = 0;
        weight = 0;
        postal_code = 0;
        domestic_total_cost = 0;
        international_total_cost = 0;
        shipments_counter = 0;

        JComboBox_bl = false;
        JComboBox_1_bl = false;
        JComboBox_2_bl = false;
        JComboBox_3_bl = false;


    }

    //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    // Initialize the contents of the frame.

    private void initialize() 
    {
        frmPos = new JFrame();
        frmPos.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Christos\\workspace\\PostOffice\\Envelope_64x64.png"));
        frmPos.setTitle("e - Post Office");
        frmPos.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        frmPos.setBounds(100, 100, 448, 438);
        frmPos.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmPos.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

//*** CODE WHICH CHANGES THE ICON OF THE JAR FILE *** 
            frmPos.setIconImage( new imageIcon( getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "Envelope_64x64.png" ) ) );
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect this code to do? How could Java code change the icon of a jar file? Have you read the documentation of JFrame.setIconImage()? Where is the png file in the jar?

Comment: The png file is in the same folder with the project and the jar file.